# Range query with elasticsearch for date saved as type "text"

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to search for documents falls on a given date range but the range query doesn't return any result.

Field mapping: 
TestDate
type    "text"
fields
keyword 
type    "keyword"
ignore_above    256

I have tried this   "range": {"TestDate": {"gte": "2015-01-01","lte":"2015-02-01"}}

I want all the documents satisfying the above condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the field as a `date` instead, otherwise it won't work being mapped as `text`

```
{
   ...
   "TestDate": {
     "type": "date"
   }
   ...
}
```

Only then your `range` query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "TestDate": {
        "gte": "2015-01-01",
        "lte":"2015-02-01"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done it using filter and added new timeobject as date. and it becomes "filter": [
                    {
                        "range": {"timeObject": {"gte": "2019-03-17T00:00:00",
                                                 "lte": "2019-03-17T12:59:59",
                                                 "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                                                 }}
                    }

Comment: Please update your question, it's more legible than in comments.